# Plotly: how to create a filled area with a color gradient?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to create a filled squared in plotly in R, like so:

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    x = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
    y = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
    type = 'scatter',
    fill = 'toself',
    fillcolor = '#ab63fa',
    hoveron = 'points+fills',
    marker = list(
      color = '#ab63fa'
    ),
    line = list(
      color = '#ab63fa'
    ),
    text = "Points + Fills",
    hoverinfo = 'text'
  ) 
p
```

But that is color with a rainbow gradient like the cube in the mesh plot of [this webpage](https://plot.ly/r/3d-mesh/). How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I probably have misunderstood you at first and have created a **plot_ly** - plot, how I understood your question - see text and example below the horizontal line.

But then I got doubts, if that was what you were looking for. Unfortunately I do not have an answer in **plot_ly** terms for what you presumably are asking for but can offer something in the **ggplotly** -style.

After defining the number of areas `n` a new data frame is made, which builds two columns in which the x-column is divided into `n` parts and the y-column is repeats the y-value (1) `n` times.

Then the `ggplot`is made with `geom_area`. The color comes in through `scale_color_gradientn`. This method plots n areas at each position on the x-axis with a varying color. So by changing `n` you change the number of those areas. Just reduce `n` and you will see the single areas as bars.

I think that demonstrates for a simple case what can be done.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
# define number of segments
n = 400 

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, by = 1/n), y = rep(1, n+1))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) #+ geom_point()
pp <- p + geom_area(aes(group =x, color =x)) +
  theme_minimal() + #coord_flip() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = max(1, 10 - 1)/10, alpha = 1)) 
ggplotly(pp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

First *solution*:

In the code below I have build a data frame first and then used `transform` and type `groupby` to define in the styles-list the two colors for the two values in `df$y`. 
If I look to the webpage you are pointing to I see a blue-ish color, no gradient. So I am assuming you want color with code `#ab63fa`. I have used two colors for the four points - which are grouped into 2 groups - *black* and *#ab63fa*.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
       y = c(0, 0, 1, 1))

plot_ly(
  type = 'scatter',
  x = df$x,
  y = df$y,
  mode = 'markers',
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'groupby',
      groups = df$y,
      styles = list(
        list(target = 0, value = list(marker =list(color = '#ab63fa'))),
        list(target = 1, value = list(marker =list(color = 'black')))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This code is based on an example from [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/group-by/)